# What is the most optimal way to visit all races' starting territories?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I am after completing [Turkey Lurkey](https://www.wowhead.com/achievement=3559/turkey-lurkey), part of the [Pilgrim's Bounty](https://www.wowhead.com/pilgrims-bounty) event in World of Warcraft. I play as an Alliance and I am level 70. Also I am a Monk meaning I have a "free" teleport to Stormwind.

What is the most optimal way to visit all races' starting territories?

Comment: @dly how does one get to Dalaran in BFA?

Comment: I think @dly meant Dalaran - Northrend, the original Dalaran. There should be plenty of Horde characters around there, but be aware you'll be kicked out of their side of the city if you try to enter. You can hang around the entrance or the bank though, and get every race/class if you hang around long enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At level 70 you'll have a hard time getting them all. This is as close as you can get:

1. Try to collect all Alliance races directly in **Stormwind**.
2. Fly from Stormwind down to **Booty Bay**. There are a lot of people questing in Elwynn, Westfall, Stranglethorn and they're all very close to each others, Alliance and Horde alike (especially in both Stranglethorns).
3. From Booty Bay you can take the **ship to Ratchet**.
4. From there you can visit the Orcs and Tauren in their starting areas as well as search the **Barrens** for possible victims, which are quite popular as well.
5. Hearth back to Stormwind and use the Deeprun Tram to **Ironforge**. From there you'll have to fly up to Tirisfal (Undead) and/or Eversong/Ghostlands (Blood Elves)
6. Visit **Hellfire Peninsula** from time to time and check for people leveling there. There's a portal back to Stormwind at the entrance, making it easy to travel between both.
7. Same with **Dalaran** (Northrend). It's also a good idea to have your Hearthstone here, because you have more options to travel around from here (at least at level 70).
8. If it still works: **PVP**. Join random battlegrounds and poke them there. Rogues and PVP are a good combination and you'll almost always have a few of them with you.

Comment: I will confirm that **PVP** is still an option, but you need to be out of combat to use the item. Which is kind of hard during a RBG, but not impossible.

Answer (score 0):

In northrend at Valliance Keep there is a Quest [Friends in Dalaran](https://www.wowhead.com/quest=29609/friends-in-dalaran) it will help you go to dalaran, which you can find there a portals into the main cities of Allied Races.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This is exactly what I did, sadly, I could find almost no people there, let alone horde rogues. Also in the hall with the portals there was **only one**: to Stormwind. I haven't played the game since WotLK and I am confused as hell.

Comment: @IvankaTodorova , they removed all portals from Dalaran except those to Orgrimmar and Stormwind. They did that in Cataclysm because having those portals there was too convenient. They did the same to the portals in Shattrath. So this answer is unfortunately not applicable. Source: https://wow.gamepedia.com/Dalaran#Portals

Comment: Currently, the area with the most portals is the Legion version of Dalaran (which has a whopping 10 portals), but you can't access that until you get the quest to do so at level 98+ or get portaled there by a Mage.  By comparison, BfA's hubs only have 4 portals.